# В каком языке можно генерировать и хранить методы?

Tags: кодогенераторы, метапрограммирование

В каком языке программирования (не использующем сборщик мусора) можно генерировать код метода, сохранить его и в следующем запуске программы воспользоваться?

Какие вообще способы существуют?

Comment: .NET с JIT-компиляцией подойдёт? А вообще-то компилятор C написан на C, так что сгенерировать плагин и подключить его возможно хоть при этом, хоть при следующем запуске.

Comment: А в чем разница между байт-кодом виртуальной машиной (скажем, LLVM) и байт-кодом физического процессора? Кроме того, что с байт-кодом физического процессора больше возни и хуже переносимость?

Comment: А, вообще, на любом (Тьюринг-полном), т.к. компилятор можно написать на любом языке. Задача «сгенерировать из некоего языка байт-код и выполнить его» сводится к именно этому.

Компилятор не нужно писать на интерпретируемых языках, где можно использовать `eval`, но у них у всех виртуальные машины.

Но, почему-то, я подозреваю, что автор не хочет писать компилятор. Поэтому поинтересуюсь — а зачем Вам это такое надо, какую цель (генерация кода явно не самоцель задачи) хотите получить? Возможно, тут оно и не нужно...

Comment: Ну можно вспомнить forth. Там и следующего запуска ждать не надо.

Comment: В Форте есть VM, но нет ООП 8-)

Answer (score 3):

Можно во многих, разный лишь уровень сервиса, предоставляемый вам компилятором/стандартной библиотекой. Если вы можете сгенерировать файл с данными, то вы можете сгенерировать и исполняемый модуль.

Например, в .NET вы можете [скомпилировать исходник .NET-класса в сборку](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/RuntimeCompilation.aspx), поскольку компилятор -- часть фреймворка .NET. После успешной компиляции вы сразу же сможете подключить полученную сборку через Assembly.Load.

Похожая возможность есть и у Java.

С другими языками, не содержащими компилятора в рантайм-библиотеке, придётся самостоятельно генерировать исполняемый модуль в формате вашей ОС. Эта задача выполнима, ведь компиляторы обычно пишутся на целевом языке. Другой вопрос, захотите ли вы брать на себя эту достаточно трудоёмкую задачу.

PS: .NET не выполняется виртуальной машиной, у него JIT-компилятор.

Comment: У LLVM тоже JIT, но даже из названия видны слова «виртуальная машина.» Как по мне, так просто грань давно стерта и избегать виртуальных машин смысла, обычно, никакого нет.

Comment: @drdaeman: вы правы, но ТС почему-то хочет именно чтобы виртуальной машины не было. Судя по всему, ему нужно, чтобы было что-то сложнее чем `eval`. Хотя `eval` -- вовсе не фишка "интерпретируемых" языков.

Comment: В LLVM нет VM, это чистый compilator framework. Но в ее API (по крайней мере то что я читал) нет такого понятия как "класс" и соответственно "метод", возможно в свежих версиях добавили.

Answer (score 3):

Вопрос какой-то мутный. В постановке автора под это определение попадает практически любой язык программирования. Любой ЯП в той или мере использует байткод (объектный код) который можно использовать при следующем запуске. Даже SQL и тот имеет понятие о прекомпилированном запросе, я уж вообще умолчу и всяких разных интерпретаторах - коих бесчисленное количество - там тоже есть понятие о некоем байткоде, который можно сохранять и запускать по мере необходимости. Аз грешен тоже являюсь автором одного скриптирующего язычка (до сих пор используется в недрах одной очень немаленькой конторы) - так что знаю о чем говорю.

Comment: я 4 часа назад изменил вопрос, Вы видимо час назад все еще отвечали на старый,в котором упоминается виртуальная машина ?

Answer (score 2):

Автор такой хитрый.

> В каком языке программирования (**не использующем виртуальную машину**)
> можно генерировать код метода, сохранить его и в следующем запуске программы воспользоваться?

Если мы можем сгенерировать код и сохранить его, то это нужно сделать так, чтобы можно было легко его загрузить обратно. Грузить двоичный код? Это неудобно.

Если хочется подобной гибкости, то в любом случае придётся использовать какое-то подобие байткода. Или выгружать прямо как исходный код.

По-теме: на ум приходит Common Lisp.

Comment: Интересует "выгружать прямо как исходный код", у этой технологии есть название? в каких яп это доступно?

Comment: В Common Lisp такое точно есть. Ещё наверное у Factor и у быть может Prolog, но не уверен. Термин? Интроспекция близко -- но не то.

Comment: @Vladimir: почему же грузить двоичный код неудобно? [`LoadLibrary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175.aspx) + [`GetProcAddress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212.aspx) (Windows native), [`Assembly.Load`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.load.aspx) + [`Assembly.GetTypes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.gettypes.aspx) (.NET) -- что может быть проще?

Comment: @Vladimir Gordeev: Чтобы не оставаться во экосистеме Microsoft, туда же ещё [`dlopen`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/dlopen.html) + [`dlsym`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/dlsym.html) и немного многословные [трюки для Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60764/how-should-i-load-jars-dynamically-at-runtime).

Comment: ну да, обычная загрузка внешней либы

Comment: вопрос похоже можно переформулировать: "существуют ли компилируемые реализации homoiconic языков без сборки мусора ?" Т.е. язык должен уметь (а) дампить заданную часть программы в текстовом виде, (б) не использовать сборку мусора и (в) иметь в составе рантайма динамический компилятор. Если честно, мне с такими требованиями в голову приходит только Форт (Forth) причем только реализации со словом (=функцией) DIS или DISASM.

Comment: термин называется "homoiconic language" т.е. язык by design содержит средства работы с программой как с данными, причем чаще всего в рантайме

Answer (score -2):

Необходима более подробная информация о конкретном приложении, об окружении в котором его планируется запускать, и о требованиях ТЗ, иначе единственный ответ -- используйте для запуска приложения команду make, пересобирая его из исходных кодов на С++ (единственный mainstream язык с ООП и без сборки мусора).

На самом деле вполне себе решение -- запхайте весь свой проприеритарный коммерчески значимый код в бинарную библиотеку без исходников, а модифицируемую часть таскайте в исходниках, и собирайте в исполняемый файл при запуске приложения.

Иначе можно дофантазироваться до создания еще одного суперкомпилятора языка метапрограммирования 8-)

- который из коробки умеет работать с AST-деревьями (а не со строками
  содержащими программу -- как представление программы в первую очередь
  приходят в голову именно деревья),
- содержит непосредственно в
  спецификации именно языка (набор формальных правил) а не его
  реализации (дистрибутив под конкретную платформу) средства хранения/ввода/вывода AST-дерева в текстовом виде (текстовый файл, строковая переменная, запись в текстовом поле БД)
- функционал преобразования AST-деревьев (pattern matching, унификация, перезапись элементов с backtrackingом)
- включает средства описания грамматик всех активно используемых языков программирования чтобы использовать готовый рабочий код
- поддерживает все динамические структуры данных (например списки, деревья, стеки, hashed map/dict из Python) + стандартную библиотеку алгоритмов на этих структурах
- умеет всю компиляторную ботву из Dragon Book (от парсинга до кодогенератора) и полторы сотни алгоритмов оптимизаций из GCC
- встроенный в рантайм-библиотеку динамический оптимизирующий компилятор в машинный код (на базе LLVM)
- ручное управление памятью или контролируемая сборка мусора
- ООП модель (классы, объекты, интерфейсы, наследование, вся ботва в лучших традициях SmallTalk)
- и все это оптимизированное под hard realtime на облаке многопроцессорных многопоточных SMP-узлах beowulf HA/HPC кластерах на переконфигурируемых процессорах с динамической FPGA/SRAM-аппаратной архитектурой (а фигли мелочиться 8-)

Comment: зря минусуете, это (1) полный развернутый ответ на вопрос и (2) тренды computer science на следующие лет 20, особенно если появятся реально работающие квантовые компьютеры -- весь багаж приложений придется адаптировать под новые аппаратные архитектуры, и создание средств и языков трансформации программ в этом случае вещь неизбежная